# What is "illegal invocation" error that stops my program from working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, windows, macos

I was developing a program in JavaScript, when each time the button is pressed the image should alternate on each press- if it is currently the "box open" image, it should switch to the "box closed" image.Similarly, if it is currently on closed, it should witch to the "box open". I am however facing an "illegal invocation" error How can this be solves?

```js
var jackbox = document.getElementById("jackbox");                                               
                                                
  function click()                                              
  {                                             
    if (this.id == "Jump out,Jack!")                                                
    {                                               
      document.getElementById("jackbox").src = "https://www.paulneve.com/pp/jackbox-open.jpg";                                              
                                                
    }                                               
    else(this.id == "Jump out,Jack")                                                
    {                                               
      document.getElementById("jackbox").src = "https://www.paulneve.com/pp/jackbox-open.jpg";                                              
                                                
    }                                               
                                                
  }                                             
                                                
document.getElementById("toggle").onclick = open;
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center; height: 280px;">
    <img id="jackbox" src="https://www.paulneve.com/pp/jackbox-closed.jpg" />
    <br/>
    <button id="toggle">Jump out, Jack!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You should not be using the nearly-three-decades-old `onclick`-style event-properties. Instead use the modern and far superior `addEventListener` technique.

Comment: What is `open`? And no elements have id values as in your function; that would not be possible anyway as id attribute values cannot have spaces.

Comment: Your `click` function is never actually used, btw. And you shouldn't make assumptions about what `this` _is_ like that.

Comment: Also where exactly do you get that error? The error should be associated with some line of code.

Answer (score 1):

#### **There are two major issues with your code:**

1. `document.getElementById("toggle").onclick = open;` should be `document.getElementById("toggle").onclick = click;` because the function that you want to execute on click is the `click` function.

   > **Note:**
   >
   > As mentioned by *Dai* in the comments, you should prefer using
   > `addEventListener`. Like this:
   >
   > ```js
   > document.getElementById("toggle").addEventListener("click", click);
   > ```

2. This `else(this.id == "Jump out,Jack")` is invalid javascript, in `else` statement you do not have to provide a condition. Either remove the condition or change `else` to `else if`. Like this:

   ```js
   if (this.id == "Jump out,Jack!") {
     document.getElementById("jackbox").src = "https://www.paulneve.com/pp/jackbox-open.jpg";
   } else {
     document.getElementById("jackbox").src = "https://www.paulneve.com/pp/jackbox-open.jpg";
   }
   ```

   **OR**

   ```js
   if (this.id == "Jump out,Jack!") {
     document.getElementById("jackbox").src = "https://www.paulneve.com/pp/jackbox-open.jpg";
   } else if (this.id == "Jump out,Jack") {
     document.getElementById("jackbox").src = "https://www.paulneve.com/pp/jackbox-open.jpg";
   }
   ```

---

#### **Final Code:**

```js
const jackbox = document.getElementById("jackbox");

function click() {
  if (this.id == "Jump out,Jack!") {
    document.getElementById("jackbox").src = "https://www.paulneve.com/pp/jackbox-open.jpg";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("jackbox").src = "https://www.paulneve.com/pp/jackbox-open.jpg";
  }
}

document.getElementById("toggle").addEventListener("click", click);
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center; height: 280px;">
  <img id="jackbox" src="https://www.paulneve.com/pp/jackbox-closed.jpg" />
  <br />
  <button id="toggle">Jump out, Jack!</button>
</div>
```